# Relative component query selectors

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1, deftjs

ExtJS 4.1 & DeftJS 0.6.8

The documentation says `"References to view components can be established via the control annotation and view-relative component query selectors"`

Documentation example:

```
control: {
        submitButton: 'panel > button[text="Submit"]'
    }
```

So in my case I want to get access to a menu's button that is nested like this:

```
  ...
  extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
  lid: 'mytreepanel',

  dockedItems: [{
     xtype: 'toolbar',
     lid: 'mybbar',
     items: [{
        xtype: 'splitbutton',
        lid: 'mysplitbutton',
        menu: {
           lid: 'mymenu',
           items: [{
              lid: 'createFolder',
              text: 'Create folder',
           }]
        }
     }]
  }]
```

My attempts:

```
control: {
         createFolder: {
            selector : '[lid=createFolder]',
         // selector : 'menu[lid=createFolder]',
         // selector : 'mytreepanel > menu[lid=createFolder]',
         // selector : 'treepanel > toolbar > splitbutton > menu[lid=createFolder]',
            listeners: {
               click: 'createFolder'
            }
         }
}
```

Nothing worked. Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add `mixins: ['Deft.mixin.Controllable']` which I forgot to make the view controllable.

So now everything works fine with:

```
createFolder: {
            selector : '[lid=createFolder]',
            listeners: {
               click: 'createFolder'
            }
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know in which documentation you found your example (`control: { submitButton: 'panel > button[text="Submit"]' }`), but it doesn't work for me at all.

By following [sencha documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller) I've created following controller class:

```
Ext.define('Pandora.controller.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    init: function() {
        this.control({
            '[lid=mytreepanel] menu[lid=mymenu] menuitem[lid=createFolder]': {
                click: function(){ alert(123); }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

With this definition of `control` click is working. Also note how the click handler is attached. You must provide callback, not a string.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. None of these worked though. Also tried some more variations based on your attempts.

Comment: I now fixed it, see my answer. The documentation example is taken from DeftJS.